# Is there a way to extract a website database just to see the structure

Tags: html, sql, copy, extract

There is a site that I would like to replicate i would like to know how there database is structured. Is there a tool that can help with this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible because the web pages do not have (direct) information on the underlying data dictionary. They have HTML, JS, CSS. They have no data model not even SQL queries.

You can look at the HTML/JS code which might give you some ideas, that indirectly, lead you to a possible design. This is the work any professional database designer should be able to do.

You would need to ask the web site owners what is the data dictionary or use some form of cracking (illegal in most countries, I guess) to have access to the server/dbms.

But even if you could have access to the data dictionary it is not necessarily obvious how that translates into the web pages you are vieweing. That's because usually there is data transformation (business rules) to arrive to the web pages, usually through some form of templating.

What you need is reverse engineering, and for that the main tool is the brain. You could use some scripting to extract useful data, eg, label elements or table headings.